# How to set text without changing inner element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<h3 id="price">0.00<sup id="category">N/A</sup></h3>
```

I am using ajax to replace the `<h3>` tag and sup tag under the `<h3>`, but after setting the value using `JQuery` it replace all in a single,

here is my snippet;

```
$("#price").text('120.25');
$("#category").text('Bacon');
```

My result is only showing **'120.25'**,and the category is not showing

How to solve this?

Comment: Please show what your desired resulting HTML would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're modifying the `h3` element. Instead have separate elements for each of your dynamic values and just update what you need.

```js
$("#price").text('120.25');
$("#category").text('Bacon');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><span id="price">0.00</span><sup id="category">N/A</sup></h3>
```

Comment: it should be noted that this requires the original markup to be altered. (probably the best choice IF you can) - I also included some alternate methods if that cannot be done in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

`text()` function recover all elements inside in the your `<h3>` tag. To achieve this you can prefer `html()` function and write it all at once.

**#Solution 1**

```js
function change(){
  $("#price").html('120.25'+'<sup id="category">Bacon</sup>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="price">0.00<sup id="category">N/A</sup></h3>
<button onClick='change();'>Change it </button>
```

**#Solution 2**

You can define all elements at the same level. For example;

```
<tag1>
  <insidetag1>Some Text Here</insidetag1>
  <insidetag2>Some Text Here</insidetag2>
</tag1>
```

If you prefer this solution, you can set texts with `text()` function selecting them seperately.

Comment: The first solution here breaks any attached event handlers if there are any.  Please show actual code for the second one on altering the text for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be done, here I show some with a recommendation to alter the original markup with a span and manipulate that)

NOTE: This is really several answers in one to illustrate the differences.

`<h3><span id="price-alter">0.00</span><sup id="category-alter">N/A</sup></h3>`

```js
$(function() {
  // text at the start with original markup, NOTE it has text nodes of both
  let torig = $("#price").text();
  // original text of node 0
  let torigPrice = $("#price").contents().get(0).nodeValue;
  let torigCat = $("#category").text();
  console.log("torig:", torigPrice, "|", torigCat);

  // direct maniplulation of price-2 and its child category-2
  let torigone2 = $("#price-2").contents().get(0).nodeValue;
  $("#price-2").contents().get(0).nodeValue = "2.34";
  $("#category-2").text("Butter");

  // direct maniplulation another (yea, don't do this remove/re-add)
  $("#category-another").remove();
  $("#price-another").text('786.32');
  $("#price-another").append("<sup id='category-another'>Not Good<sup>");

  // direct maniplulation of alternate markup and its child (probably the right way if you can)
  $("#price-alter").text("432.34");
  $("#category-alter").text("Milk");

  // clone the original, manipulate it and append it as new element (just to demonstrate)
  // most often best with "table" rows you want to clone and insert
  let myclone = $("#price").clone(true);
  // new id just to demonstrate (no dup id)
  myclone.attr("id", "#price" + "-new");
  // text of the clone
  let cloneText = myclone.text();
  //  clone and remove the old category from the clone
  let savedCat = myclone.find('#category').clone(true);
  myclone.find('#category').remove();
  // new id just to demonstrate (no dup id)
  savedCat.attr('id', 'category-new');
  savedCat.text('New Cat Clone');
  myclone.find('#category').remove();
  // text of the new clone price
  myclone.text("123.67");
  // add cloned category then append it back
  savedCat.appendTo(myclone);
  $('#new-markup').after(myclone);
  let tClone = myclone.text();

  console.log("Values:", torig, "|", torig, "|", torigone2, "|", tClone, "|", $("#price-2").text());

  // what you did originally
  $("#price").text('120.25');
  $("#category").text('Bacon');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Original (whoops):</div>
<h3 id="price">0.00<sup id="category">N/A</sup></h3>
<div>Original (another):</div>
<h3 id="price-another">0.00<sup id="category-another">N/A</sup></h3>
<div>Alternate markup:</div>
<h3><span id="price-alter">0.00</span><sup id="category-alter">N/A</sup></h3>


<div>Original-2 textNode:</div>
<h3 id="price-2">0.00<sup id="category-2">N/A</sup></h3>
<div id="new-markup">NEW markup:</div>
```